# Convert passwords from htpasswd to htdigest

Tags: apache, .htpasswd, htdigest

On a Server I like to switch from Apache `auth_basic` to `auth_digest` for security reasons.

Is there a way to convert the old `.htpasswd` file to the `htdigest` format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `htpasswd` program [usually creates](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html) encrypted passwords. If you used **MD5**, **SHA1**, **bcrypt** or **crypt** for encrypting passwords, you almost can’t recover the original data. These cryptographic functions are called *one-way*: you can create a hash but you can’t restore the original value. It’s the main purpose of the one-way functions.

As I know, in the HTTP Digest algorithm, [RFC2617](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), introduced so called *realm*, some [unique] string for a challenge. This information is used for hashing passwords. It’s not possible to reuse a file with passwords because, for the Basic Authentication, these passwords were hashed without the realm information.

Try to ask your users to change their passwords after the first authentication.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I know the passwords in htdigest are in md5 also. So my thought was to simply copy the md5 hashes from htpasswd to the htdigest passwd file.

Comment: @rechengehirn I added a note.

Comment: md5, especially unsalted is not a "one-way" only nowadays. SHA1 isn't doing that much better, only bcrypt does well as it's salted correctly etc etc.